# How can I create a byte packet in C?

Tags: c

I just wanted to know how could I create a byte packet in C. I need a packet like this:

**Type:** Unisgned Char 1 byte

**Name:** Char 7 bytes

**Mac:** Char 13 bytes

**Random Number:** Char 7 bytes

**Data:** Char 50 bytes

This would be a structure with 1 byte chars, but the problem is the size:

```
struct PDU{
    unsigned char code;
    char name;
    char mac;
    char RNumber;
    char data;
}
```

How could I change the size of the chars?

Thanks

Comment: `stdint.h` has defintions for 8 bit long singed and unsigned ints. Use those for fine grained size control.

Comment: "I know that I have to use a structure" - code up a structure and see if it fits your needs? And just a suggestion, if you can't declare a C structure conforming to the fields you laid out in your question, something tells me a structure layout is just the tip of what is about to be a very, *very* big iceberg; like what you *need* this for.

Comment: @Sibidharan: "`char` cannot be an `unsigned` as it doesn't have a sign"??? I suggest you do some research (like, taking the most basic C course, for example) before you emit statements of this type. In particularly if you choose to precede them with statement of the "are you kidding" type!!!

Comment: @Sibidharan In C, char doesn't store ASCII (which is 7 bits anyway, while char is 8 or more bits), it stores bytes, which *may* represent text using some encoding.

Comment: @barakmanos I apologise. As it states, char are stored in 1 byte, it is pretty sure no space for the sign, but only for the value. I said that statement in that assumption.

Comment: @hyde I referred from this site https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/C_chars.html

Comment: @Sibidharan signed char gives you at least the -127 to 127 range. (-128 to 127 is common) 7bit value + 1bit sign
unsigned char gives you at least the 0 to 255 range.

Comment: @Sibidharan also, that page is at least partially wrong on multiple levels. The C standard makes no guarantee that A..Z nor a..z are contiguous, though it does guarantee 0..9 are such. Nor does the C standard guarantee the values are "ASCII" so the opening sentence is wrong off block. In case you're wondering why that is important consider what malaise takes place when coding a loop assuming continunity for A..Z [using an OS with a character representation like **this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout)

Comment: Thanks all for letting me know this. :) :)

Comment: @Sibidharan: "no space for the sign"??? The context of this post is **not** characters in a text file (sorry, couldn't think of any other way to refer to that comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the size of `char` - but you *can* make lists of `char`s long enough for each of the items (these are called "arrays"):

```
struct PDU{
    unsigned char code;
    char name[7];
    char mac[13];
    char RNumber[7];
    char data[50];
};
```

Beware of *structure padding*: a C compiler is free to add padding bytes between each of these items. It may do so because accessing 'word aligned' data usually is faster than 'any byte'. You can instruct the compiler to not do so by adding a special compiler instruction before this structure, usually (check your compiler manual!) something like

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

If there are other structure definitions after this one that don't need their padding removed, look up the instruction to restore Normal Services again and add it below this strcture definition.

When copying data into this structure, it is absolutely *vital* that you do not copy 'out of bounds' and overwrite the data in the next item. (That goes for all programs in C but I might as well mention it again.)